# Does the white tanooki suit appear in the world 5 castle of super mario 3d land?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I've went and done the lives cheat thing and committed Mario suicide like 25 times in the castle and it still hasn't appeared. I'm pretty sure I had it for the first two stars I got on that level though! (I have the 2nd & 3rd stars) Just need that first one as I'm kind of a dunce and missed it the first time around...

If not does anyone know a cheat to get past Bowser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already completed the level once, and go back and try to complete the level again, the Invincibilty Leaf (the item that gives you the white Tanooki suit) will not appear anymore, no matter how many times you die.

The same goes for P-Wings - if you have already completed a level once, then you will not get to use the P-Wing in that level.

Comment: Thank-you didnt know that it means bad news for the whole rest of the game now though :-s crraaaaapp lol,, i shall have to just become awesome and do it myself - this must be karmas way of teaching me a lesson for hijacking my kids toys lol.... Temporarily of course but still lol...

Comment: @Kathy You're welcome! Since you found the answer useful, you could upvote/accept the answer, which lets other people know it was helpful to you (and does, in full honesty, reward the answerer with rep, and the asker with (a small amount) rep as well).

Answer (score -5):

You can get it again you just need to die like 1,000 times. Try it no mater what. It works for me!

Comment: The first star coin is on top of the Thwomp.